# Redirect page to secure page

Tags: iis, redirect, url-rewriting, plesk

I cant seem to find an exact answer on the web to suit my problem. I'm trying to redirect/rewrite:

```
http://www.ccy.com.au/availability/booking.asp
https://secure.ccy.com.au/availability/booking.asp
```

SSL has been setup on secure domain. It's been done through plesk(v11.0.9_build20120609.17 os_Windows 2008) and I'm using IIS 7.5

Is there a way to achieve this sort of redirect/rewrite as I'm very new to server related tasks. Thank you in advance!

p.s I'll provide other information I may have missed!

Comment: In plesk, secure.ccy.com.au is an alias for www.ccy.com.au. If that means anything to anyone!

Answer (score 0):

In your booking.asp file, can you simply do:

```
<%
Response.Redirect("https://secure.ccy.com.au/availability/booking.asp")
%>
```

Comment: I think we are on the right track! Apparently I have an infinite loop.
In plesk:
secure.ccy.com.au  Alias for ccy.com.au
Does this have something to do with the infinite looping? If so, Do I have to change the hosting type (a.k.a the alias for ccy.com.au)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a neophyte with Plesk, I've only had one client with it. It sounds like both of your domains are answering to the same request, so when you hit booking, you redirect to booking secure, and it continues.

You can try something like this:

    <%
    IF Request.ServerVariables("HTTPS") <> "ON"
    THEN Response.Redirect("https://secure.ccy.com.au/availability/booking.asp")

My classic ASP syntax memory is waning. :)

Comment: hey thanks for the help! Still getting infinite loop unfortunately. But you have given me more things to try out though! Thank you again! Yes my ASP ain't flash either haha

Comment: Do you have any "redirecting" going on in Plesk itself? I'm not sure how their aliasing works, on IIS if you have a website serving two domains (secure and unsecure), a loop like this shouldn't happen because when you hit booking.asp on the secure site, it shouldn't redirect as per the Request.ServerVariables("HTTPS")... and it should leave you at that page.

Check for server side redirects, and remove those if you want code to handle it.

Comment: I'm not too sure, I have the main domain "ccy.com.au" and under it a domain alias which is "secure.ccy.com.au" so anytime I go to secure.ccy it just goes straight to ccy.com.au. so when I put that code in that you suggested it just goes in an infinite loop! So my guess is that the domain alias is redirecting automatically to its parent domain "ccy.com.au"